# MASK R-CNN, why val_mrcnn_bbox_loss and val_mrcnn_mask_loss are 0?

Tags: image, classification, mask, image-segmentation, faster-rcnn

```
Starting at epoch 0. LR=0.002

Checkpoint Path: /content/Mask_RCNN/logs/crack_images20200707T0451/mask_rcnn_crack_images_{epoch:04d}.h5
Selecting layers to train
fpn_c5p5               (Conv2D)
fpn_c4p4               (Conv2D)
fpn_c3p3               (Conv2D)
fpn_c2p2               (Conv2D)
fpn_p5                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p2                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p3                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p4                 (Conv2D)
In model:  rpn_model
    rpn_conv_shared        (Conv2D)
    rpn_class_raw          (Conv2D)
    rpn_bbox_pred          (Conv2D)
mrcnn_mask_conv1       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn1         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv2       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn2         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv1      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn1        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv3       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn3         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv2      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn2        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv4       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn4         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_bbox_fc          (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_deconv      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_logits     (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask             (TimeDistributed)
Epoch 1/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2546s - loss: 59.9573 - rpn_class_loss: 4.9158 - rpn_bbox_loss: 55.0416 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.5773e-06 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 42.9541 - val_rpn_class_loss: 8.3271 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 34.6270 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 4.1246e-06 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2466s - loss: 47.9174 - rpn_class_loss: 3.4403 - rpn_bbox_loss: 44.4434 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0044 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0198 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0096 - val_loss: 40.8780 - val_rpn_class_loss: 1.7095 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 39.1685 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 4.3463e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2432s - loss: 45.2084 - rpn_class_loss: 2.1342 - rpn_bbox_loss: 43.0547 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0030 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0062 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0103 - val_loss: 40.2231 - val_rpn_class_loss: 1.9367 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 38.2864 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 7.5409e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2402s - loss: 44.3991 - rpn_class_loss: 2.0594 - rpn_bbox_loss: 42.3396 - mrcnn_class_loss: 7.5638e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 42.4247 - val_rpn_class_loss: 3.2007 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 39.2239 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 7.1904e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2404s - loss: 47.2541 - rpn_class_loss: 3.9966 - rpn_bbox_loss: 43.2575 - mrcnn_class_loss: 4.8513e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 36.8668 - val_rpn_class_loss: 0.6245 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 36.2422 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 3.1065e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2402s - loss: 41.3224 - rpn_class_loss: 3.4068 - rpn_bbox_loss: 37.9156 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.7582e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 30.5534 - val_rpn_class_loss: 1.2449 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 29.3085 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.4438e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2391s - loss: 45.0313 - rpn_class_loss: 3.8534 - rpn_bbox_loss: 41.1548 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0021 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0122 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0089 - val_loss: 41.7707 - val_rpn_class_loss: 0.9706 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 40.8001 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 3.5309e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2435s - loss: 41.4883 - rpn_class_loss: 2.7715 - rpn_bbox_loss: 38.6841 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0016 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0224 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0086 - val_loss: 42.0558 - val_rpn_class_loss: 2.9680 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 39.0877 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.6321e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2473s - loss: 41.6691 - rpn_class_loss: 2.3281 - rpn_bbox_loss: 39.3410 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.8393e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 38.0360 - val_rpn_class_loss: 1.7419 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 36.2941 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.2530e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2450s - loss: 39.7236 - rpn_class_loss: 2.0216 - rpn_bbox_loss: 37.6904 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0010 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0026 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0080 - val_loss: 33.0290 - val_rpn_class_loss: 6.8746 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 26.1544 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.5153e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2397s - loss: 40.1832 - rpn_class_loss: 3.3822 - rpn_bbox_loss: 36.8010 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.4559e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 36.0607 - val_rpn_class_loss: 4.1198 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 31.9409 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.4557e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2391s - loss: 31.5999 - rpn_class_loss: 2.2898 - rpn_bbox_loss: 29.3101 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.5380e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 28.0113 - val_rpn_class_loss: 0.6510 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 27.3603 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.1243e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2441s - loss: 29.5633 - rpn_class_loss: 2.0158 - rpn_bbox_loss: 27.5475 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.8165e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 24.3744 - val_rpn_class_loss: 1.0115 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 23.3629 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.1410e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2424s - loss: 29.5249 - rpn_class_loss: 2.8759 - rpn_bbox_loss: 26.6115 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0013 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0202 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0160 - val_loss: 21.7251 - val_rpn_class_loss: 1.2835 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 20.4416 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 1.4686e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2441s - loss: 25.1142 - rpn_class_loss: 2.5004 - rpn_bbox_loss: 22.6137 - mrcnn_class_loss: 1.3815e-05 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 31.8563 - val_rpn_class_loss: 0.5517 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 31.3045 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 1.5712e-05 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 16/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2371s - loss: 28.6811 - rpn_class_loss: 2.5408 - rpn_bbox_loss: 26.1402 - mrcnn_class_loss: 9.1934e-06 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 20.2755 - val_rpn_class_loss: 0.6740 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 19.6015 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 6.0320e-06 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 17/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2427s - loss: 26.1218 - rpn_class_loss: 4.1050 - rpn_bbox_loss: 21.9986 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0018 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0074 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0091 - val_loss: 23.0992 - val_rpn_class_loss: 3.4643 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 19.6348 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 5.0068e-06 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 18/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2487s - loss: 27.5055 - rpn_class_loss: 2.8223 - rpn_bbox_loss: 24.6514 - mrcnn_class_loss: 0.0017 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0155 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0145 - val_loss: 20.8848 - val_rpn_class_loss: 2.3465 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 18.5383 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.8133e-06 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 19/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2537s - loss: 21.7046 - rpn_class_loss: 1.6853 - rpn_bbox_loss: 20.0193 - mrcnn_class_loss: 3.7229e-06 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 27.4155 - val_rpn_class_loss: 8.5852 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 18.8303 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 4.4346e-06 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 20/20
100/100 [==============================] - 2537s - loss: 25.0851 - rpn_class_loss: 2.9776 - rpn_bbox_loss: 22.1076 - mrcnn_class_loss: 2.8539e-06 - mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 17.3773 - val_rpn_class_loss: 2.7509 - val_rpn_bbox_loss: 14.6263 - val_mrcnn_class_loss: 2.5272e-06 - val_mrcnn_bbox_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_mrcnn_mask_loss: 0.0000e+00
Fine tune Resnet stage 4 and up
Training took 814.59 minutes
```

I ran 20 epochs and noticed that the val_mrcnn_bbox_loss and val_mrcnn_mask_loss were 0 right from the beginning and I would like to ask:

1. What does each loss mean? Is there perhaps a documentation explaining them?
2. Why are the two losses 0? Is there something wrong?

---

What I have done was:

- Draw labels using a website called Labelbox
- Export the labels as a JSON file
- Run a script to convert the JSON file to suit the COCO format
- Run MASK-RCNN

---

So far I'm unable to produce any segmentations for my predictions but I am guessing it is due to the low number of epochs I have ran.

I am new to classification through segmentation and I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have images in val set copied from train set?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no straight docs, but you may find some comment on github repo: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1112

rpn_class_loss: How well the Region Proposal Network separates background with objects

rpn_bbox_loss : How well the RPN localize objects

mrcnn_bbox_loss : How well the Mask RCNN localize objects

mrcnn_class_loss : How well the Mask RCNN recognize each class of object

mrcnn_mask_loss : How well the Mask RCNN segment objects

That makes a bigger loss:
loss : A combination (surely an addition) of all the smaller losses.

2. Extremely small val loss (0 or close to) may happen when val data is just (partly) copies of train data. Don't mix this sets.